# How to find the aws-sdk version in v3 javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm aware we can find the current aws-sdk(v2) version in lambda runtime from `AWS.VERSION` environment variable. In v3, aws-sdk is modularized, is there a way to find the which version of the aws-sdk client lib used in lambda runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import { version } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3/package.json' assert { type: 'json' };
```

Comment: It doesn't work. First, it fails with `Module needs an import assertion of type json`, then, if the assertion is fixed, it fails with `The requested module '@aws-sdk/client-s3/package.json' does not provide an export named 'version'`.

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin to deal with the json import do this: `import { version } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3/package.json' assert { type: 'json' }';` That will let you read it as a json document and version is most definitely is a property of that object.

Comment: I had to do the following: `import aws_package from '@aws-sdk/client-s3/package.json' assert { type: 'json' };` and then access `aws_package.version`

Comment: @JohnLindal Thanks - indeed the more recent Node imports assertions are now often required. Updated answer.